# Quantiles by factor levels in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame and I'm trying to create a new variable in the data frame that has the quantiles of a continuous variable `var1`, for each level of a factor `strata`.

```
# some data
set.seed(472)
dat <- data.frame(var1 = rnorm(50, 10, 3)^2,
                  strata = factor(sample(LETTERS[1:5], size = 50, replace = TRUE))
                  )

# function to get quantiles
qfun <- function(x, q = 5) {
    quantile <- cut(x, breaks = quantile(x, probs = 0:q/q), 
        include.lowest = TRUE, labels = 1:q)
    quantile
}
```

I tried using two methods, neither of which produce a usable result. Firstly, I tried using `aggregate` to apply `qfun` to each level of `strata`:

```
qdat <- with(dat, aggregate(var1, list(strata), FUN = qfun))
```

This returns the quantiles by factor level, but the output is hard to coerce back into a data frame (e.g., using `unlist` does not line the new variable values up with the correct rows in the data frame).

A second approach was to do this in steps:

```
tmp1 <- with(dat, split(var1, strata))
tmp2 <- lapply(tmp1, qfun)
tmp3 <- unlist(tmp2)
dat$quintiles <- tmp3
```

Again, this calculates the quantiles correctly for each factor level, but obviously, as with `aggregate` they aren't in the correct order in the data frame. We can check this by putting the quantile "bins" into the data frame.

```
# get quantile bins
qfun2 <- function(x, q = 5) {
    quantile <- cut(x, breaks = quantile(x, probs = 0:q/q), 
        include.lowest = TRUE)
    quantile
}

tmp11 <- with(dat, split(var1, strata))
tmp22 <- lapply(tmp11, qfun2)
tmp33 <- unlist(tmp22)
dat$quintiles2 <- tmp33
```

Many of the values of `var1` are outside of the bins of `quantile2`. I feel like i'm missing something simple. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your issue is that you don't really want to aggregate, but use `ave`, (or `data.table` or `plyr`)

```
qdat <- transform(dat, qq = ave(var1, strata, FUN = qfun))

#using plyr
library(plyr)

qdat <- ddply(dat, .(strata), mutate, qq = qfun(var1))

#using data.table (my preference)


dat[, qq := qfun(var1), by = strata]
```

Aggregate usually implies returning an object that is smaller that the original. (inthis case you were getting a data.frame where `x` was a `list` of 1 element for each strata.

Comment: (+1) for 3 different methods

Comment: @mnel thanks so much! I knew I must have been missing something simple - I always forget about `ave`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ave` on your `dat` data frame. Full example with your simulated data and `qfun` function:

```
# some data
set.seed(472)
dat <- data.frame(var1 = rnorm(50, 10, 3)^2,
              strata = factor(sample(LETTERS[1:5], size = 50, replace = TRUE))
              )

# function to get quantiles
qfun <- function(x, q = 5) {
    quantile <- cut(x, breaks = quantile(x, probs = 0:q/q), 
        include.lowest = TRUE, labels = 1:q)
    quantile
}
```

And my addition...

```
dat$q <- ave(dat$var1,dat$strata,FUN=qfun)
```