# Calculating percentiles by factor using ave() in r

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate percentiles (0.3 & 0.7) of a z-score variable (BuildingZ) by factor level (DistrictName). My research so far has pointed me in the direction of the ave() function, allowing me to sort by factor level, but given my "newness" to working in R, I don't really know how to work around this issue. Here's what I have tried:

Create the data frame with the variables I need:

```
MathGap2=data.frame(MathGap$DistrictName, MathGap$BuildingName, MathGap$Grade, MathGap$BuildingZ)
```

Use the `ave()` function to calculate the desired quantile as a new column:

```
MathGap2$Thirty<-ave(MathGap2$BuildingZ, MathGap2$DistrictName, fun=quantile(MathGap2$BuildingZ, c(0.3)))
```

I'm not sure if invoking "quantile" is even valid, or whether I'd have to write a function for this (which is beyond my experience). I've seen similar attempts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15561976/quantiles-by-factor-levels-in-r), but can't get them to work.

P.S. If it's any help, some of the factors may only occur 1-3 times. I'm not sure if this affects the ability to calculate percentiles or not. While this seems silly, ignore the shady math for now; simply trying to replicate an existing study as close as possible.

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example. Anyway, try `ave(MathGap2$BuildingZ, MathGap2$DistrictName, FUN= function(x) quantile(x, 0.3))`.

Comment: Try using `quantile` on a subgroup outside of `ave` to see if it suits your needs, like `x = with(MathGap2, BuildingZ[DistrictName==DistrictName[1]]; quantile(x,.3)` Once you've tweaked the args to `quantile` so they produce your desired output, then go back to embedding it in `ave`