# Calculating AVERAGEIF in R by factor level

Tags: r, excel

In [Calculating percentiles by factor using ave() in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31074888/calculating-percentiles-by-factor-using-ave-in-r), I asked how to calculate percentiles within the `ave()` function. With that task finished, I'm faced with a more difficult task.

Take the following data:

```
DistrictName            Building Name   X2.Yr.AVG       Thirty          Seventy
Ionia Public Schools    Emerson         -0.337464323    -0.196387489    -0.046524185
Ionia Public Schools    Jefferson       -0.318673587    -0.196387489    -0.046524185
Ionia Public Schools    Ionia Middle    -0.290854669    -0.196387489    -0.046524185
Ionia Public Schools    Ionia Middle    -0.288202752    -0.196387489    -0.046524185
Ionia Public Schools    Twin Rivers El  -0.23426755     -0.196387489    -0.046524185
Ionia Public Schools    R.B. Boyce El   -0.202319963    -0.196387489    -0.046524185
Ionia Public Schools    Twin Rivers El  -0.142995221    -0.196387489    -0.046524185
Ionia Public Schools    Emerson         -0.141620372    -0.196387489    -0.046524185
Ionia Public Schools    Jefferson       -0.141407078    -0.196387489    -0.046524185
Ionia Public Schools    R.B. Boyce El   -0.115530249    -0.196387489    -0.046524185
Ionia Public Schools    Ionia Middle    -0.111449269    -0.196387489    -0.046524185
Ionia Public Schools    Twin Rivers El  -0.054918339    -0.196387489    -0.046524185
Ionia Public Schools    Jefferson       -0.045591501    -0.196387489    -0.046524185
Ionia Public Schools    A.A. Rather     0.002251298     -0.196387489    -0.046524185
Ionia Public Schools    R.B. Boyce El   0.020669633     -0.196387489    -0.046524185
Ionia Public Schools    Emerson         0.065064968     -0.196387489    -0.046524185
Ionia Public Schools    A.A. Rather     0.182776319     -0.196387489    -0.046524185
```

What I'm trying to do is something akin to what the `AVERAGEIF` function in Excel. In Excel, I can say `=AVERAGEIF(C2:C18, "<-.196387489")`, which spits out the average value -0.278630474. I need something in R that allows me to do the following: I want to create  new variables for the average value of:
1) any values of `X2.Yr.AVG` that are smaller than the value of `Thirty` 
2) any values that are larger than the value of `Seventy`

The catch is that I need to be able to perform this operation in a large data frame with 722 levels for the factor `DistrictName`. In the step for calculating the percentiles, I used the `ave()` function to create percentiles according to the desired factor as follows:

```
    MATHgap$Thirty<-ave(MATHgap$X2.Yr.AVG, MATHgap$DistrictName, 
       FUN= function(x) quantile(x, 0.3))
```

and

```
    MATHgap$Seventy<-ave(MATHgap$X2.Yr.AVG, MATHgap$DistrictName, 
       FUN= function(x) quantile(x, 0.7))
```

Is there any way to do something akin to AVERAGEIF within `ave()` so that the operation is repeated for each value of `DistrictName` independently of the others? I.e, Ionia Public Schools should have an average value for `X2.Yr.AVG` less than -0.196387489 and for `X2.Yr.AVG` greater than -0.046524185, and I want to be able to perform the same function for all districts using their respective values for `X2.Yr.AVG`, `Thirty`, and `Seventy`.

If this is confusing, apologies.

Comment: `by(X2.Yr.AVG, MATHgap$DistrictName, function(x) {p = quantile(x, c(0.3, 0.7)); mean(x[(x>p[1] & x<p[2])])})` `by, aggregate, ave, tapply` basically do the same thing with different syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `dplyr`:

```
MATHgap %>%
  group_by(DistrictName) %>%
  mutate(MeanLT30 = mean(X2.Yr.AVG[X2.Yr.AVG < Thirty]),
    MeantGT70 = mean(X2.Yr.AVG[X2.Yr.AVG > Seventy]))
```